# Switch between text editor and other windows

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does Visual Studio 2013 support keyboard shortcuts for switching between windows? f.e. the text editor and "find results" window? I tried F6 but it does not work.

Comment: `ctrl + tab` it shows you Active Tools and Active Files

Comment: @Mark, ctrl + tab only works for active files, can I switch between active tools and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help by [Mark's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844904/switch-between-text-editor-and-find-results-window#comment42254533_26844904), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then use arrow keys (right and left) to switch between tools and files.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Press **Alt + F7** to move through Active tool windows. To return back to text editor use **Ctrl + Tab**.